# How do I modify the min and max value of a jQueryMobile slider at runtime?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-slider

So I have a slider in my HTML document:

```
<input type="range" name="testSlider" id="testSlider" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
```

I want to modify the min and max range at run time, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

I apologize if this is obvious, but I'm really struggling with this seemingly obvious task. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `$('#testSlider').attr('min',myNewMinValue);` and `$('#testSlider').attr('max',myNewMaxValue);` ?

Comment: You can use jQuery Slider Widget's [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option). Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
$('#testSlider').attr('min',MINVALUE);
$('#testSlider').attr('max',MAXVALUE);
```

And then you refresh the slider

```
$('#testSlider').slider( "refresh" );
```

OR

```
$("#testSlider").slider( "option", { min: MINVALUE, max: MAXVALUE} );
```